# Provide us a detailed explanation to calculate the Mellin transform of a cosine function, and get the closed form of a related sum

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, mobius-function, mellin-transform, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to know how define and compute the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) (see the definition of previous integral transform in the **Wikipedia**'s article) of $\cos\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}x\right)$. My genuine problem is consider the **Möbius function** expressed as 
$$\mu(n)=\sum_{\substack{(k,n)=1\\1\leq k\leq n}}\cos\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}\right),$$ then I am interested in calculate the Mellin transform of the following related function, here thus $n\geq 1$ is a fixed integer, $$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{\substack{(k,n)=1\\1\leq k\leq n}}\cos\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}x\right)$$ as $$\left\{ \mathcal{M}  f_n\right\}(s)=\sum_{\substack{(k,n)=1\\1\leq k\leq n}}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cos\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}x\right)dx,$$ using that **this integral transform is linear**.

> **Question 1.** Can you explain how get easily the Mellin transform of one of the summands, thus $$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cos\left(2\pi\frac{k}{n}x\right)dx?$$ Where is defined the integral transform? (I say where is defined the result.)

After,

> **Question 2.** Can you state the more simplified form (if there are  simplifications to get the sum) for $$\left\{ \mathcal{M}  f_n\right\}(s)?$$ **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: **All users,** the main question was solved and the second (more optional), now I try do more calculations (using the functional equation), but I believe that there are no closed form for such sum on $gcd(k,n)=1$ with $1\leq k\leq n$. The main problem for me was how start to calculate Mellin transforms. Thanks all user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{k}{n}$ for $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \cos(2\pi a x) \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{ia2\pi x} + x^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{-ia2\pi x} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

The first integral:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{ia2\pi x} \mathrm{d}x
&= \left(\frac{-1}{ia2\pi}\right)^{s} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} y^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{-y} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \left(\frac{-1}{ia2\pi}\right)^{s} \Gamma(s) \\
&= \frac{1}{(a2\pi)^{s}} \Gamma(s) \mathrm{e}^{is\pi/2}
\end{align}

The second integral:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{-ia2\pi x} \mathrm{d}x
&= \frac{1}{(ia2\pi)^{s}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} y^{s-1} \mathrm{e}^{-y} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{(ia2\pi)^{s}} \Gamma(s) \\
&= \frac{1}{(a2\pi)^{s}} \Gamma(s) \mathrm{e}^{-is\pi/2}
\end{align}

Thus,
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \cos(2\pi a x) \mathrm{d}x
&= \frac{1}{2} \Big[\frac{1}{(a2\pi)^{s}} \Gamma(s) \mathrm{e}^{is\pi/2} + 
\frac{1}{(a2\pi)^{s}} \Gamma(s) \mathrm{e}^{-is\pi/2} \Big] \\
&= \frac{1}{(a2\pi)^{s}} \Gamma(s) \cos\left(\frac{s\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align}

### Addendum

Here is another solution that avoids the issue addressed in the comment made by user243301.

In Volume 2 of [Higher Transcendental Functions](http://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechAUTHORS:20140123-104529738) (Bateman Manuscript), Section 9.10, Equation 1 we
have a generalization of the fresnel integrals attributed to Bohmer:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{C}(x,a) &= \int\limits_{x}^{\infty} z^{a-1} \cos(z) \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Big[\mathrm{e}^{i\pi a/2} \Gamma(a,-ix) + \mathrm{e}^{-i\pi a/2} \Gamma(a,ix)\Big]
\end{align}

Thus
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{C}(0,a) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} z^{a-1} \cos(z) \mathrm{d}z 
= \Gamma(a) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)
\end{equation}

For our integral, let $z=2\pi ax$
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \cos(2\pi as) \mathrm{d}x 
= (2\pi a)^{-s} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} z^{s-1} \cos(z) \mathrm{d}z
= (2\pi a)^{-s} \Gamma(s) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Very thanks much, your answer is very valuable because now I've understand more things. I've understand that you use $\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}/2)$, after the first integral (the second is the same calculation) you do the change of variable $y=-ia2\pi x$, and I've undertand subsequent calculations. The only that I don't know is how calculate the **new upper limit of integration** as $\infty$ (also I've observed that since $x=\infty$ then should be $y=-ia2\pi\infty$) but I **don't know if this make sense**. PLease how do you justify the upper limit of integration. Thanks, I accept the answer.

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution useful. I chose to interpret the limits of integration as moduli. This took care of the negative sign and allowed me to evaluate the integral. I checked my solution with Wolfram Alpha (using a = 1) and it matched. Maybe someone else can provide a proof for this.

Comment: Very thanks much to you and other user for your answer.

Comment: You can't do the complex change of variable $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-i a x}dx = (ia)^{-s} \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{- x} dx = (ia)^{-s} \Gamma(s)$ ($a \in \mathbb{R}$) without some complex analysis : contour integration or analytic continuation.  @user243301

Comment: There is [the complex analysis proof I meant](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1662805/276986)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/FourCos2.pdf,

$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cos\dfrac{2\pi kx}{n}~dx=\dfrac{n^s\Gamma(s)}{2^s\pi^sk^s}\sin\dfrac{\pi(1-s)}{2}=\dfrac{n^s\Gamma(s)}{2^s\pi^sk^s}\cos\dfrac{\pi s}{2}$

Comment: I believe that there is a typo in your answer. Very thanks much for your attention and reference.

Comment: $\pi$ in the denominator should be raised to the power s.