# Mellin transform $\frac1{\cos(x)-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to show the following formulas?

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1}}{\cos (x)-1} \, dx=-i^{-s} (2 \pi )^{s-1} \left(-s+(-i)^s i^s\right) \zeta (2-s) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)$$
and
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} \sin (x)}{(\cos (x)-1)^2} \, dx=(-1)^{1-s} \left((-1)^s-1\right) \zeta (s-2) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \Gamma (s)$$

Comment: it should be true only for $Re(s) \in (0,1)$. Expand $\frac{1}{\cos(x)-1}$ as a series in $e^{i nx}$, and show [that $\Gamma(s) e^{i \pi s /2} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-i x} dx, Re(s) \in (0,1)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645954/simpler-way-to-evaluate-the-fourier-transform-of-exp-lefti-ex-right/1662805#1662805) but  you need some complex analysis theorems (analytic continuation, complex integration).

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut everything disappeared :)